# Javascript Submit Select Form with Multiple Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a select form that allows users to select multiple items. I am trying to avoid having a submit button so I wanted to figure out a way to have the form submit when the user clicks out of the form.

I used `<select onchange="this.form.submit()">` but this submits the form whenever they click any option and I want it to work for selecting multiple items.

Is there any way I can have it submit the form when the form loses focus?

Answer (score 0):

You can use onblur event.

```
$("select").blur(function(){ /* do stuff */ });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2mSUS/3/

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick but you still have to do some action to lose focus, like click outside or tab out:

```
onfocusout="this.form.submit()";
```